# Why is it the case that $|z-\alpha|\leq n\left|\frac{p(z)}{p'(z)}\right|$ for a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ with root $\alpha$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, approximation

I was reading [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02207694) which claimed the following:

$$|z-\alpha|\leq n\left|\frac{p(z)}{p'(z)}\right|$$

Where $p$ is a polynomial with degree $n$, and $\alpha$ is the zero of $p$ closest to $z$.

Why is this the case?

I know that if we replace $z$ with $\delta=z-\alpha$, then we get an equivalent polynomial $q(\delta)$ with degree $n$, which would mean $\left|\frac{p(z)}{p'(z)}\right|=\left|\frac{q(\delta)}{q'(\delta)}\right|$. However, I can't blindly apply the triangle inequality, so I'm struggling to figure out how to prove this.

Comment: A free version of that article is available here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225654837_Numerical_computation_of_polynomial_zeros_by_means_of_Aberth%27s_method

Comment: Where exactly is that inequality claimed in the article?

Comment: The claim is not true if $p(z) = (z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$ with $\alpha \neq \beta$ at the point $z = \beta$. Perhaps there was additional context which would make it true.

Comment: The inequality holds if $\alpha$ is the zero closest to $z$. Before writing an answer, it would be good to know if that is what you mean.

Comment: if $P$ has roots $\alpha=\alpha_1, ..\alpha_n$ and say for simplicity they are distinct, the inequality is equivalent to $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z-\alpha_k}| \le \frac{1}{|z-\alpha|}$ and that of course is not generally true, but it is if $z$ is in the region where $|z-\alpha| \le |z-\alpha_k|$ for all $k$ as @Martin noted

Comment: The actual statement is that for a number $z$, the disk with centre $z$ and radius $n\left|\frac{p(z)}{p'(z)}\right|$ will contain a root of $p$. Sorry for the confusion, I thought the two statements were equivalent without checking properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are the zeros of $p$, counted with multiplicity, then
$$
 p(z) = c(z - a_1) \cdots (z-a_n)
$$
implies
$$
 \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{1}{z-a_1} + \cdots +\frac{1}{z-a_n} 
$$
and therefore
$$
 \left| \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \right| \le \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{|z-a_k|} 
$$
for all $z \in \Bbb C \setminus \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$.

Now assume that $p'(z) \ne 0$ and let $\alpha \in \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$ be the zero closest to $z$. If $p(z) \ne 0$ then
$$
\left| \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \right| \le \frac{n}{|z-\alpha|} 
\implies |z-\alpha| \le n \left| \frac{p(z)}{p'(z)} \right| \, .
$$
If $p(z)= 0$ then $\alpha = z$ and  the last inequality holds trivially.

Comment: What do you mean by zero closest to $z$? Here $z$ is the variable

Comment: @ZFR: The statement is that, for each $z$, the inequality holds with $\alpha$ chosen as the zero closest to $z$.